# Refresh page after updating via AJAX request in Epi Server

Tags: javascript, dojo, episerver

I have an Epi server page template with following property:

```
        [Display(
            Name = "Selection Box",
            GroupName = Global.GroupNames.Contact
        )]
        public virtual bool SelectionBox { get; set; }
```

In the view I have something like this:

```
@if (PageEditing.PageIsInEditMode)
{

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model.CurrentPage.SelectionBox,
        new
        {
            @class = "toggle",
            @data_url = Url.Action("UpdatePage", "DefaultPage"),
        })


    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.toggle').change(function () {
                var self = $(this);
                var url = self.data('url');
                var value = self.prop('checked');

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: { selected: value },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Basically what it does, it when I change checkbox value, it sends request to controller and updates the value on the page. What I'm missing is that when this sucesfully happens, I would like the page reload but I can't find a way to do it.

I'm not using OOTB on page editing here, as I'm looking for a way to give editors some adavnced editing for the component, yet I don't want to build a dojo widget. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Use window.location.reload(); in the success function

Comment: If you're going to reload the page regardless when the checkbox is clicked, you might as well use a form and POST the checkbox value to the `UpdatePage` action method and have it render the page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chapter on "On-page editing with client-side rendering" in the developer guides, see https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/editing/on-page-editing-with-client-side-rendering/

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using Ajax is to design a SPA (single page application) where no page reload is required. If you are looking for a page reload, you can probably do

`window.location.reload();`

But a page reload might cause you to lose data return by the Ajax call.